# Either [Char] a -> IO a function

Tags: haskell

How can I write a function so that `Left x` to an IO error but `Right x` returns its result as usual, i.e. the function has signature `Either [Char] a -> IO a`?

Basically I want the `Left err` result to become the `err` in the IO Monad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One simple definition is:

```
f :: Either String a -> IO a
f = either (ioError . userError) return
```

Note that we can make this generic with `fail`, but it's really a historical accident that `fail` is in `Monad` to begin with, so I wouldn't use this definition:

```
f :: Monad m => Either String a -> m a
f = either fail return
```

A better generic version might use the `MonadError` class:

```
import Control.Monad.Error.Class

f :: MonadError e m => Either String a -> m a
f = either (throwError . strMsg) return
```

Comment: Though I'd say `Monad m =>` being the most general _possible_ signature doesn't mean it would necessarily be a _good_ idea to make it that general. That `fail` is a method of `Monad` is mostly so pattern match failure in `do`-notation `let`-statements can be caught, but I wouldn't really use it on purpose since most monads don't have the error-handling ability that `IO` has.